# Sharp end on Sweep Gradient

Tags: flutter, gradient

[image]

In the above image the red colour has sharp end, how to make it smooth like the other colours.

0.1666666666666667 is average stop for every colour

```
Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.red,
        gradient: SweepGradient(
          colors: [
            Colors.purple,
            Colors.indigo,
            Colors.blue,
            Colors.green,
            Colors.yellow,
            Colors.orange,
            Colors.red
          ],
          stops: [
            0.0,
            0.1666666666666667,
            0.1666666666666667 * 2,
            0.1666666666666667 * 3,
            0.1666666666666667 * 4,
            0.1666666666666667 * 5,
            0.1666666666666667 * 6,
          ],
        ),
      ),
      child: Scaffold(),
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add the first color again at last.

If your first color is purple. So, add purple again at last

```
          colors: [
            Colors.purple,
            Colors.indigo,
            Colors.blue,
            Colors.green,
            Colors.yellow,
            Colors.orange,
            Colors.red,
            Colors.purple,
          ],
```